# Django: Single model for multiple tables

Tags: django-models

I have a main table
Slideshow
then a site specific table that captures a few extra details for that site.
Site1_Slideshow

In a web app (specific to a site) i want a single model i.e. Slideshow that combines the 2 tables above.
Currently i have the code below, but i dont think this is correct. I cant do things like
s = Slideshow.objects.get(slideshowId=1) as Slideshows only has the properties featurecategory and slideshow. So how can i have an model called Slideshow that is composed of these 2 tables but looks like it was a single db table.

```
class SlideshowAbstract(models.Model):
    slideshowid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column=u'SlideshowId') # Field name made lowercase.
    headline = models.TextField(db_column=u'Headline') # Field name made lowercase.
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'Slideshow'

class Slideshow(models.Model):
    slideshow = models.OneToOneField(SlideshowAbstract, primary_key=True,db_column=u'SlideshowId')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.slideshow.headline
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'Site1_Slideshow'
```

Answer (score 0):

Think i found the solution.
On the Site1_Slideshow you need to add a column for django to use, that i presume is always the same as primary key value.
Its name is SlideshowAbstract_ptr_id
Once that is added you can change the Slideshow model to be

```
class Slideshow(SlideshowAbstract):
   featureCategory = models.ForeignKey(Featurecategory,db_column=u'FeatureCategoryId')
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.headline
class Meta:
    db_table = u'Site1_Slideshow'
```

So doable but not the nicest if you are not doing "model first" and already have the schema. Would be good to be able to override the name of the _ptr_id column.

I did try adding the following to Slideshow too see if i could map this ptr col to the primary key
    slideshowabstract_ptr_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column=u'SlideshowId')

but no cigar.
I havent tested inserts either but ...objects.all() works